Issue with iOS Flutter App where API sometimes showing DioExpception in iOS
I am working on a project where once user fills the Address field, there is drop down showing list of addresses and once user selects the address, the Postal code is extracted from the address and is send to an API which will get the State and City and it will be auto populated in the two fields.
It working fine in Android, even in iOS Simulator. But in iOS App on Test Flight it sometimes shows following error:
DioException [unknown]: null
Error: HttpException: Connection reset by peer 
Below is the screenshot the exception received.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Did you confirm with API team that they are closing connection after request fullfilled ?

Thanks for the revert. As such, it seems to be a Dio issue. Change dit to Http and its working fine now.
